# Kamailio autoreload

Tags: python, python-3.x, kamailio

I am new to Kamailio.

Is it possible to autoreload Kamailio if Kamailio's settings are changed (DB kamailio, kamailio.cfg, kamailio.py, etc.) by python script or any config ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really bad idea, if you have any error in that config it will not start.

But there are few third-party scripts which can autorestart Systemd service.

For example, this one
https://github.com/stevekrenzel/autoreload